# Cordova ajax call kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 311

Tags: ajax, cordova

Anyone encountered this error? **kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 311**?

I wrote a simple cordova application running in iPad (iOS 9 up). This applications calls an HTTPS api but throws this error `kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 311`.

> Pleas note that the HTTPS Server has a valid CA Issued SSL Certificate.

I googled a lot on this error but without any luck and only managed to found this [cfStreamErrorHTTPSProxyFailureUnexpectedResponseToCONNECTMethod](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cfnetwork/cfnetworkerrors/1416956-cfstreamerrorhttpsproxyfailureun) that has an int value of 311 and it says that

> The HTTPS proxy returned an unexpected status code, such as a 3xx
>   redirect

Indeed the resource that i am invoking is returning a 302 which unfortunately i have no control of.

And to access the https server, i have to specifically connect to a wifi proxy where the IP address is whitelisted in the https server.

I hope someone from this great community could provide me some light on this error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I also have received the same error. The problem is that you are accessing network through a proxy which needs to be authenticated before you send a request. 
In your case, generally if you are accessing internet in the system browser, you might have proxy settings(along with authentication) in your browser or system preferences -> network -> Advanced -> Proxies. 
In order to address the authentication issues while URL requests, Apple has given documentation in this regard - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html. 
For a simple model implementation just refer to [Simple example of NSURLSession with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711816/simple-example-of-nsurlsession-with-authentication)